# Python Overlays : A case for monkey Patching

Tags: python, python-import, monkeypatching

I am trying to wrap/monkey patch modules in python. I am trying to develop a a clean means of implementing this that does not interfere with any existing code.

## Problem

Given a script that imports some `CLASS` from a `MODULE`

```
from MODULE import CLASS
```

I would like to replace `MODULE` with another `_MODULE_`. Where `_MODULE_` is a patch for the original `MODULE`. The cleanest interface I can see for this is as follows.

```
from overlay import MODULE # Switches MODULE for _MODULE
from MODULE import CLASS   # Original import now uses _MODULE_
```

This is basically monkey patching modules in the same way one would monkey patch classes, functions and methods. I believe if this is done correctly one could consistently patch code in a project specific kind of way.

What is the best way of implementing this ?

Comment: I'm not sure why there are votes to close my question as being too broad, perhaps it's vague, but it's certainly a focused problem. Perhaps I'm being a bit verbose ? Either way I just edited the entire thing and cleaned it up some.

Comment: It's really hard to find a question in the post. You have to read closely a huge wall of text and coding examples. Perhaps you should state the question up front, and then provide all of the code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I trimmed out the MWE, I'll post it as an answer if someone asks but have left it off for now to preserve my unanswered status. Hopefully this leaves the door open to a more robust approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import wrapt
>>> @wrapt.when_imported('collections')
... def hook(collections):
...     OldOrderedDict = collections.OrderedDict
...     class MyOrderedDict(OldOrderedDict):
...         def monkey(self):
...             print('ook ook')
...     collections.OrderedDict = MyOrderedDict
...     
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict().monkey()
ook ook
```

Answer (score 0):

@wim's answer is certainly better but as I have been fiddling with this for a while here is my best bash at this. I assumes the following folder/file structure :

```
PACKAGE/
  overlay.py
  _decimal_.py
  __main__.py
```

within `_decimal_.py` I include the following lines

```
from decimal import *
__version__ = "X.Y"
```

within `overlay.py` I have :

```
import importlib
import inspect
import builtins
import os
from pathlib import Path

modsep      = '.'

class OverlayImporter(object):

 def __init__(self, *args, path = None, root = None, _import_ = __import__, **kvps):
  super().__init__(*args, **kvps)
  self.mask = "_{}_"
  self.root = Path(root or os.path.dirname(inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[1][0]).__file__))
  self.mods = self.modules()
  # Substitutes Import Functionality
  builtins.__import__ = self
  self.imp = _import_
  self.lom = []

 def __call__(self, name, *args) : # (self, *args, *kvps):  
  # Hooks the import statement
  if self.mapToTarget(name) in self.mods.keys() :
   if name in self.lom :
    return self.imp(name, *args)
   self.lom.append(name)
   return importlib.import_module(self.mapToTarget(name)) # This is a little black magic as we ignore the args
  return self.imp(name, *args)

 def mapToTarget(self, name) :
  """Maps request to the overlay module"""
  # Converts PACKAGE.MODULE to overlay._PACKAGE_._MODULE_
  return modsep.join([self.mask.format(part) for part in name.split(modsep)])

 def modules(self) : 
  """ Lists the overlays implemented within a directory """
  ext = '.py'
  mod = lambda parts, ext : [part[:-len(ext)] if enum + 1 == len(parts) else part for enum, part in enumerate(parts)]
  lst = [(mod(file.relative_to(self.root).parts, ext), file) for file in self.root.rglob('*'+ext)]
  return {modsep.join(item[0][:-1]) if item[0][-1] == "__init__" else modsep.join(item[0]) : item[1] for item in lst}
```

and within `__main_.py` I have

```
from overlay import OverlayImporter
OverlayImporter()
import decimal
print(decimal.__version__)
```

Commenting the first two lines in the main file toggles between the patched and un-patched versions of decimal.